# tkinter display label text in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, label

I am very inexperienced with python and i'm trying to write a simple script that presents the letters "A", "B" and "C" in a tkinter window after a certain key is pressed. So far my script only displays the last letter of the letter list. Any ideas on how to make it work?
Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
# create gui window    
Main_window = Tk()
# set the configuration of the window
Main_window.geometry("220x100")
 
my_string_var =  StringVar()
#my_string_var.set("C")
 
my_label = Label(Main_window, textvariable = my_string_var).pack()


def myevent():
    dict = ['A', 'B']
    for i in dict:
        my_string_var.set(i)
        print(my_string_var.get())
        Main_window.update_idletasks()

# create a Button widget 
btn = Button(Main_window,
              text = "press to change let", command = lambda: myevent()).pack()
```

I tried defining a function to loop through my list of letters and I thought every letter would appear on the tkinter window.

Comment: May I ask, what you really want in the end ? I can imagine different solutions and I'm not quite sure what exactly you ask for. You want all latter in the same lable and combined within the for-loop? You want to actually see that latter are added to the lable (I ask because I see you imported `sleep` which isn't a good idea to use in context of the GUI-Event-Loop).

Comment: Do you want to print  like this  'A' then 'B' then 'C'?

Comment: Yes I want to print A then B then C on the window..

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the answer to my question in order to help others who might wonder about the same thing...

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.IntVar()
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=lambda: var.set(1))
button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="center")


my_string_var = tk.StringVar()
my_string_var.set('C')
# create a label widget
my_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable = my_string_var)
my_label.place(relx=.1, rely=.1, anchor = "center")

i = 0
dict = ["A", "B"]
while i < len(dict):
    button.wait_variable(var)
    my_string_var.set(dict[i])
    print(dict[i])
    i += 1
```